# Rails array column field not creating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I read all about this and how there are transactional issues in updating an array column but mine wont even create.

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :steps
  ...
end
```

Migration

```
add_column :recipes, :steps, :text, array:true, default: []
```

Output

```
$ r = Recipe.create(steps: [1,2,3])
> #<Recipe:0x007fe38ae68870 id: 27, ..., steps: [], ingredients: []>
```

Also played around with this method with no luck:

```
def add_steps(steps)
  steps_will_change!
  update_attributes steps: self.steps + steps
end
```

Comment: does it matter that you have a type text and are saving integers?

Comment: I don't think so. It will be strings that I'm saving and I tested it with ["a", "b", "c"] and no luck either.

Comment: You are testing in a console. Have you tried `reload!` in the console?

Comment: Just to reinforce Aleks's comment, your code works perfectly in Rails 4.2 here.

Comment: Executive Summary: Don't use `serialize` with PostgreSQL array columns.

Comment: @muistooshort was right. No `serialize` with array columns. It's one or the other. Thanks